# issue with a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck on this little metronome project.  It's supposed to flash back and forth between two background colors.  It works fine as long as both colors are defined (switch "col" in JS line 12 to any color and it works).  However, I'm also trying to make it so I can randomize one of the colors onclick.  I can tell (console.log) that my number randomizer is producing a correct hex color value for my variable "col" but I can't get that variable to work. I have tried "col" without quotes.

Here is a link to the codepen: http://codepen.io/Fedreg/pen/xVqwjQ/

```
    <head></head>
<body>
              <div id="title">
      flashnome
  </div>
  <div id="desc">               
    the silent metronome
      <p>
        <button onclick="slower();" id="button1">
          slower
        </button>
        <button onclick="faster();" id="button1">
          faster
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button onclick="change();" id="button1">Change Color</button>
    </p>
  </div>
 </body>


    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,700);

html, body {
        height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

#title {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        margin: auto;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 2em 0 .2em;
    }


#desc {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        margin: auto;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
    }

#button1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .7em;
        font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 8px;
    }


var x = 500;
var flashStep = 1;
var myInterval;

function change() { 
var col = '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').slice(2, 8);
  console.log(col);
}

function flash() {
  if (flashStep == 1) {
    document.bgColor = "col";
    flashStep = 2;
  } else {
    document.bgColor = "#333";
    flashStep = 1;
  }
}

function faster() {
  window.clearInterval(myInterval);
  myInterval = window.setInterval(flash, x -= 25);
}

function slower() {
  window.clearInterval(myInterval);
  myInterval = window.setInterval(flash, x += 25);
}

myInterval = window.setInterval(flash, x);

function change() { 
var col = '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').slice(2, 8);
  console.log(col);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a global variable named "randomColor" and change it.

```
 var x = 500;
    var flashStep = 1;
    var myInterval;
    var randomColor = "#FFFF00";

function change() { 
var col = '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').slice(2, 8);
  randomColor = col;
  console.log(col);
}

function flash() {
  if (flashStep == 1) {
    document.bgColor = randomColor;
    flashStep = 2;
  } else {
    document.bgColor = "#333";
    flashStep = 1;
  }
}

function faster() {
  window.clearInterval(myInterval);
  myInterval = window.setInterval(flash, x -= 25);
}

function slower() {
  window.clearInterval(myInterval);
  myInterval = window.setInterval(flash, x += 25);
}

myInterval = window.setInterval(flash, x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!  Couldn't figure out how to make the global variable change col.  Some of the basics of JS still elude me.  Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: You're most welcome. Please accept it as an answer if it solved your problem  Thanx. Let me know if there're any questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
function change() { 
    var col = '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) +     '000000').slice(2, 8);
  console.log(col);

  return col;
}

function flash() {
  if (flashStep == 1) {
    document.bgColor = change();
    flashStep = 2;
  } else {
    document.bgColor = "#333";
    flashStep = 1;
  }
}
```

You could avoid using a global Variable by using " return" in the "change()" function and then calling change() int the flash()  function.
That's a bit "better-practice" than using global variables

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to find a way to use the returned col but did not try setting bgColor = change() like you did.  Much to learn but I find I absorb it munch better by hacking projects together and working through my mistakes so really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've written the change() function *twice*. Then, inside of it you're using the *var* keyword - that makes the variable local within the change() function - nothing **outside** of that function has access to col.

Just define col as a global, above the change() function. When referencing it, do **not** enclose it in quotes - that makes it a string (the literal value "col").

So:

```
var col = false;

function change(){
    col = '#F11';
}

change();

document.bgColor = col;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!  The double change() function was just a copy/paste issue while posting the question.  I thought it was a scope issue but my attempts to fix it didn't help.  Really appreciate it!